# How to calculate the average of specific values in a column in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas data frame has 11 columns and 453 rows. I would like to calculate the average of the values in rows 450 to 453 in column 11. I would then like to add this 'average value' as a new column to my dataset.

I can use `df['average']= df[['norm']].mean`

To get the average of column 11 (here called norm). I'm not sure how to only calculate the average of specific rows within that column though?

Comment: Wait, you want the mean of last three values in the `"norm"` column added to a new column? And that new column will just have a single value and the rest `nan`?

Comment: No, I want the entire new column to have the mean value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
df["average"] = df["norm"][450:].mean()
```

Demo:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 6, 2, 3]})
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  6
3  2
4  3

>>> df["b"] = df["a"][2:].mean()
>>> df
   a         b
0  1  3.666667
1  2  3.666667
2  6  3.666667
3  2  3.666667
4  3  3.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc`?

```
df['average'] = df.loc[450:, 'norm'].mean()
```

Comment: Sorry, complete beginner here, how do I add that line into the code above? for example   df['average']= df[data.loc[450:453,'norm']].mean    doesn't work...

Comment: Do this `df['average'] = data.loc[450: 452, 'norm']`

Comment: That doesn't give me a column with the mean of the values in rows 450 to 452 in column 'norm'. It just gives me a column with 'NaN'